Quasi-abelian categories and vector spaces
Let $C$ be an Artinian, Quillen exact, $\mathbb C$-linear, essentially small category with finite-dimensional $\operatorname{Hom}$'s.
Does $C$ admit an exact, faithful functor to $\operatorname{Vect}_{\mathbb C}^\text{f.d.}$?
Is anything of this sort known for quasi-abelian $C$? For example, for the ones arising in the context of Bridgeland stability?
For Abelian $C$, the positive answer is well-known.
This question is closely related to the one I've asked previously.
However, I'd prefer to leave them as the separate ones: this one is short and abstract, —  and the another is about some very concrete situation (torsion pair).
